# subset spatial polygon df by coordinates

Tags: r, leaflet, r-sp

I am working with an spdf to build an interactive map with leaflet and shiny in r. I want to reactively subset my data according to the coordinates of the map bounds in current view (in order to plot a graph which varies accordingly).

One can subset an spdf by the data attributes, e.ge

```
spdf2 <- spdf1[spdf1$Indicator == "pop" & spdf1$Country == "US",]
```

but is it possible to subset by polygon attributes - specifically the lat and long coords of the `labpt` slot (the center of the polygon)?

Answer (score 0):

Since I am just interested in the data slot, my solution was to extract the labpt coordinates with apply,  bind the resulting matrix to the sp data portion. e.g:

```
my_df2 <- cbind(my_spdf@data, as.data.frame(t(sapply(slot(my_spdf, 'polygons'), 
                                                    function(i) slot(i, 'labpt')))))
```

Then use conventional subset/filter methods.